# Can ffmpeg set pts values of the output frames

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to make ffmpeg set the output pts values of frames?  What I want to do is re-encode a source but maintain the original pts values.

I have tried various filters but the result is always new pts values on the output.

```
ffmpeg -i source_sample.ts -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -preset fast -crf 22  -f mpegts /tmp/sample.ts
```

The above command only affects the input stream not output.

Any suggestions welcome...

Thanks

Comment: possibly http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253340/keep-timecode-in-ffmpeg

Comment: @rogerpack I tried the "setpts" already and it seems to only affect how the input is handled.  Your second suggestion seems to be only for used with the 'copy' directives.

Comment: True, maybe ask the ffmpeg-user mailing list, and/or superuser.  My guess is that if you re-encode at all the output TS is set by the encoder, dunno if any of them have this particular option...

Answer (score 4):

setpts only works when you also instruct ffmpeg to copy or transform input timestamps to output timestamps. Try adding 
        -copyts -start_at_zero
or
        -vsync passthrough